# Create DataFrame from list of dictionaries without duplicating index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a `DataFrame` using a list of dictionaries. One of the keys (`timestamp`) is shared across all those dictionaries and is supposed to be the unique index, while the other keys can change and should be the columns:

```py
full = [
    {'timestamp': 123, 'apples':1, 'oranges':1},
    {'timestamp': 227, 'apples':2, 'oranges':2},
    {'timestamp': 123, 'bananas':3, 'pears':3},
    {'timestamp': 123, 'mangos':4, 'avocados':4}]
```

Right now, I'm obtaining rows with duplicate index.

```py
pd.DataFrame(full) 

   timestamp  apples  oranges  bananas  pears  mangos  avocados
0        123     1.0      1.0      NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN
1        227     2.0      2.0      NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN
2        123     NaN      NaN      3.0    3.0     NaN       NaN
3        123     NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN     4.0       4.0
```

As you can see, I have duplicate indices even when the `timestamp` values are the same.

How can I have this, instead?

```py
   timestamp  apples  oranges  bananas  pears  mangos  avocados
0        123     1.0      1.0      3.0    3.0     4.0       4.0
1        227     2.0      2.0      NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN
```

**Raising exceptions when index is not unique**

Also, I want to make sure that there are no overlapping values for the same index. For example:

```py
full = [
    {'timestamp': 123, 'apples':1, 'oranges':1},
    {'timestamp': 227, 'apples':2, 'oranges':2},
    {'timestamp': 123, 'bananas':3, 'pears':3},
    {'timestamp': 123, 'bananas':4, 'avocados':4}]  # This row should create issues
```

The last two lines from the snippet above both contain (different) values for the `bananas` column with timestamp `123` (the index). This should not happen, and should ideally raise an exception when I try to create a DataFrame as specified above.

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame(full).groupby('timestamp', as_index=False).sum()``

Comment: @sushanth Thank you, your solution works. However, it seems quite a workaround. What if I want to raise an exception when some values are overlapping (e.g. I have two rows with the same index and they both have a value for the same column)? In your solution, it would sum up the values. But I'd like to consider it as a mistake in the data instead.

Comment: Please edit the question with relevant use case.